# I would like to have add_post_meta to return the ID instead of true or false

Tags: meta-query

I would like to know if there's a way to have the ID when we use the `add_post_meta()` function ?

I need it so I could remove it using ajax calls.

Is there a way to retrieve it or I'll have to make a query to the database to find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Codex, using `add_post_meta()` you can't. That function is supposed to return either `true` or `false`.

***However***, that function is a thin wrapper around [`add_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_metadata)...

> ```
> 1726  function add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false) {
> 1727          // make sure meta is added to the post, not a revision
> 1728          if ( $the_post = wp_is_post_revision($post_id) )
> 1729                  $post_id = $the_post;
> 1730  
> 1731          return add_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
> 1732  }
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1726

... and `add_metadata()` returns the row insert ID.

> Return Values
>
> (boolean|integer)
>       Returns `false` on failure. On success, **returns the ID of the inserted row**. However, note that the return value may instead be the
>   result of the `add_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_metadata

You can see that in the source as well:

> ```
> 73            $mid = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;
> 74    
> 75            wp_cache_delete($object_id, $meta_type . '_meta');
> 76    
> 77            do_action( "added_{$meta_type}_meta", $mid, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
> 78    
> 79            return $mid;
> 80    }
> ```
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L31

Given the source to those two functions, I don't see how `add_post_meta()` can return a `boolean` when it is just passing information to, and returning the output of, `add_metadata()`.

I just did a quick test of `add_post_meta()` on an old (3.6) install on a purely local testing server and I got the ID, not `true` or `false`. If you are getting a `boolean` I suspect it might be "the result of the `add_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter" as noted in the docs to `add_metadata()`

The problem could also be related to how your AJAX operates, but you didn't post any detail, or code, related to that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need id of meta table. There are built in wordpress functions to dealt with post meta.  You can use [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function to get it. Use [delete_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta)
to delete it. You can also use [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) if you want to update value.